# Oracle stored procedure executes within Toad, but not in SSIS execute SQL task, get Literal doesn't match format string

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssis-2012

I am having an interesting problem.  If I execute the code in Toad, regardless of what company I pass, it executes successfully.  If I execute the same script within Execute SQL task, I get an error stating Literal doesn't match format string.

Script:

```
declare
company varchar(3);
runid number;
transcount number;
returncode number;

begin
company:='APC';
runid:=0;
transcount:=0;
returncode:=0;

storedprocedurename(company, runid, transcount, returncode);

end;
```

Beginning of stored procedure in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE storedprocedurename
   (company_code IN INTERFACE_LOG.company_code%TYPE,
    run_id IN OUT NUMBER,
    transaction_count IN OUT NUMBER,
    return_code IN OUT NUMBER )
```

Error in SSIS:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "declare
company varchar(3);
runid number;
transcou..." failed with the following error: "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "triggername", line 20
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'triggername'
ORA-06512: at "storedprocedurename", line 209
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "triggername", line 20
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'triggername'
ORA-06512: at "storedprocedurename", line 135
ORA-06512: at line 1". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Any suggestions as to why SSIS cannot translate the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you posted looks like a possible reason for `ORA-01861`. It is usually related to `date` datatype when you pass a string using one format and apply `to_date` function to it which uses a completely unrelated format mask. For example:

```
SQL> select to_date('23062020', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
select to_date('23062020', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL>
```

But, if format mask matches the string, it *works*:

```
SQL> select to_date('23062020', 'ddmmyyyy') from dual;

TO_DATE(
--------
23.06.20

SQL>
```

Check the rest of your code and see whether you did something like this, maybe relying on Oracle's capabilities to implicitly convert string into date (but failed). TOAD might have used different NLS settings than SSIS, I can't tell.

Comment: no to_date's in the proc, there are a couple of TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY').  I will check into the NLS settings.

Comment: This TO_CHAR looks OK, nothing wrong with it. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, yes - as error stack says, look at stored procedure at lines 135 and 209, as well as trigger at line 20 (I suspect it just calls the procedure).

Comment: Error stack is basically useless, there is no line 209 in the proc, line 135 is just RAISE; Trigger line 20 just declares a variable: nWeekEndingDayOfWeekContract NUMBER;  Thank you for the suggestions though.

Comment: If line 135 is RAISE within EXCEPTION handler section, remove (comment) it. It'll force Oracle to display actual error line which might give you clue.

Comment: I found this in a function that is called from the proc.  Is there a way to rewrite this and remove the TO_DATE?
sWeek := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.week_ending_date,'dd-mon-yy'),'WW');
        sYear := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.week_ending_date,'dd-mon-yy'),'YY');

Comment: I told you, it is TO_DATE. OK, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So stupid, within the stored procedure, it called a function that had a to_date in it.  I changed the code below and now this works!

Was:

```
sWeek := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.week_ending_date,'dd-mon-yy'),'WW'); 
sYear := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.week_ending_date,'dd-mon-yy'),'YY');
```

Changed to:

```
sWeek := TO_CHAR(:NEW.week_ending_date,'WW');
sYear := TO_CHAR(:NEW.week_ending_date,'YY');
```